# Error while rotating disk

Tags: graphics, rotation

Trying to rotate a disk, it gets trimmed:

```
Graphics[Rotate[Disk[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0 Degree, 180 Degree}], 20 Degree]]
```

[image]

I would be pleased if you could tell me which option do I have to set to solve this problem.

Comment: Set a `PlotRange` explicitly to see the entire disk.

Comment: Also, be aware of the fact that `Rotate` will rotate an object around the center of its bounding box. If this is not what you want or expect, you can specify the point around which to rotate explicitly, e.g. `Rotate[object, angle, {0,0}]`.

Comment: As it happens, the `PlotRange` and rotation center suggestions happen to be the first two "Possible Issues" mentioned in the [documentation page of Rotate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rotate.html)...

Comment: Thank you very much Marco and Gwii.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to everyone for the help, here I resume the things you said, which solved my problem:

```
Graphics[Rotate[Disk[{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {0 Degree, 180 Degree}],20 Degree,{0, 0}],PlotRange->{{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}]
```